# Alphabet position in python

Tags: python

Newbie here...Trying to write a function that takes a string and replaces all the characters with their respective dictionary values.
Here is what I have:

```
def alphabet_position(text):

    dict = {'a':'1','b':'2','c':'3','d':'4','e':'5','f':'6','g':'7','h':'8':'i':'9','j':'10','k':'11','l':'12','m':'13','n':'14','o':'15','p':'16','q':'17','r':'18','s':'19','t':'20','u':'21','v':'22','w':'23','x':'24','y':'25','z':'26'}
    text = text.lower()
    for i in text:
        if i in dict:
            new_text = text.replace(i, dict[i])
    print (new_text)
```

But when I run:

```
alphabet_position("The sunset sets at twelve o' clock.")
```

I get:

```
the sunset sets at twelve o' cloc11.
```

meaning it only changes the last character in the string. Any ideas? Any input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `new_text` keeps being replaced by the latest result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following your logic you need to create a `new_text` string and then iteratively replace its letters. With your code, you are only replacing one letter at a time, then start from scratch with your original string:

```
def alphabet_position(text):

    dict = {'a':'1','b':'2','c':'3','d':'4','e':'5','f':'6','g':'7','h':'8','i':'9','j':'10','k':'11','l':'12','m':'13','n':'14','o':'15','p':'16','q':'17','r':'18','s':'19','t':'20','u':'21','v':'22','w':'23','x':'24','y':'25','z':'26'}
    new_text = text.lower()
    for i in new_text:
        if i in dict:
            new_text = new_text.replace(i, dict[i])
    print (new_text)
```

And as suggested by Kevin, you can optimize a bit using `set`. (adding his comment here since he deleted it: `for i in set(new_text):`) Note that this might be beneficial only for large inputs though...

Comment: I didn't see this answer when I posted and edited. Just deleted mine and voted for yours

Answer (score 2):

As your question is generally asking about "Alphabet position in python", I thought I could complement the already accepted answer with a different approach. You can take advantage of [Python's string lib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html), [char to int conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/704152/10657880) and [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to do the following:

```
import string


def alphabet_position(text):
    alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase
    return ''.join([str(ord(char)-96) if char in alphabet else char for char in text])
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is not very efficient. You are recreating the string for every character.

There are 5 `e` characters in your string. This means replace is called 5 times, even though it only actually needs to do anything the first time.

There is another approach that might be more efficient. We cant use `str.translate` unfortunately, as it's remit is [one to one replacements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25202070/1540468).

We just iterate the input and produce a new string character by character.

```
def alphabet_position2(text):

    d = {L: str(i) for i, L in enumerate('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 1)}

    result = ''
    for t in text.lower():
        result += d.get(t, t)

    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty simple approach with list comprehension.

1. Generate k:v in this format from string module, `1:b` instead of `b:1`

import string

```
def alphabet_position(text):
        alphabeths = {v: k for k, v in enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase, start=1)}
        return " ".join(str(alphabeths.get(char)) for char in text.lower() if char in alphabeths.keys())
```