# I have string of characters that i need to turn to string of ASCII numbers, how to convert it?

Tags: python, ethernet

I have string that i received through Ethernet port and i have decoded it like this:

```
data, address = p1.recvfrom(1040)  
text = data.decode('ascii')
stri = ''  
for i in text:
    stri = + ord(i)
```

Is there a way that doesn't require for loop, that can give me same string right away?

Comment: Can you give an example what the value of `data` looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a one-liner if you just want to minimize your code :

```
stri = ''.join(str(ord(c)) for c in text)
```

Or use the [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) function if you really don't want to use a loop :

```
stri = ''.join(map(lambda c: str(ord(c)),text))
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be made simple with `map` and `ord`
here is the example

```
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: str(x)+str(y), map(ord,"hello world"))
'10410110810811132119111114108100'
```

Source: [Convert string to ASCII value python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8452961/convert-string-to-ascii-value-python/8453012#8453012)

Comment: @Aurel Included source here