# User input into array - python 3

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

Hi there i am trying to put a user input into an array, so far i have:

```
#Decrypt string
def decrypt():
    print("Please enter code to be decrypted.")
    text = input(">>>")
    print("Please enter your key used to encrypt the data.")
    key = int(input(">>>"))



    #Put input into array
    #????
```

I am tring to get the input and put it in an array so that it can be referenced using

```
chr(text[1])
```

To convert it into plain text from ascii (Basic encryption and decryption).
I have found a few posts on this but they are outdated (for python2 etc...).

Thanks!

Comment: `text[1]` should already work regardless of Python2 vs Python3...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get char from string by index?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8848294/how-to-get-char-from-string-by-index)

Comment: @cricket_007 It does work, i just want to be able to refence it from the users input like you would from an array.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen i cant use that solution because some elements will be 3 letters long and i wont know what to select i also just want it as an int in a array.

Comment: show me an answer that didn't work for you because you are using python3.  I don't see how it would be different between versions.

Comment: Do you mean convert to [list of ints as in their ordinals](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8452961/5827215)?

Comment: you can `split` by some delimeter. ie `array = user_input.split(" ")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to have an indexable list to store user inputs as they come in, you can use the [built-in list class](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) and its append method:

```
keys = list();
texts = list();

def decrypt():
  print("Please enter code to be decrypted.")
  text = input(">>>")
  print("Please enter your key used to encrypt the data.")
  key = int(input(">>>"))
  texts.append(text)
  keys.append(key)
```

Now, `texts[n]` will return the nth `text` value entered by your user.

Comment: Sorry i didn't see this but i just used `text1 = text.split()` since the input comes with spaces and it works a charm, thanks though!